# Excel formula: If condition then do that condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

Some excel IF statements can get fairly long, and I am looking for an easier way to writ them. For example, if I were to write:

```
If($B$4+13=7,$B$4+13,FALSE)
```

I think it would be easier to put:

```
If($B$4+13=7,[Do the left hand side of the equation without making me re-type it], FALSE)
```

Especially if the condition is very long and complex.

Is there something I could write in place of:

```
[Do the left hand side of the equation without making me re-type it]
```

Thanks!

Comment: only thing I can think of is to put that left hand portion in it's own cell .. ie pre-calc it ahead of time, then you can just reference that cell in multiple places.

Comment: Your purpose is similar to the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) where we no longer have to test for an error before using the intended formula to gain a result. There is no **IFTRUE** function as yet but they are running out of things to create so you might get lucky in a future version. In the meanwhile, a simple UDF could accomplish this. [history] People were using UDFs to accomplish IFERROR behavior long before IFERROR was around. If you supplied a sample formula, I suspect that it could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not do

=If($B$4+13=7,7,FALSE)

The comparison has two parts. You know what you want to compare with, so instead of writing the formula again just use the comparison value in the TRUE part.

Edit: Another approach to streamline a long, complex IF statement with repetitive formulas:

```
=IF(A1="x",<complex formula>*100,<complex formula>*200)
```

rewrite to

```
=<complex formula>*if(A1="x",100,200)
```

Comment: Good workaround - technically I believe @Ditto's recommendation in the comment answers the direct question as asked, but overall I would say reframing the formula like this is a better way to look at things. I would put this in the vain of things like using "MAX(A1,0)" instead of "=IF(A1>0,A1,0)".

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon, exactly. Depending on what calculations are being done in the IF statement, the approach to streamline the formula may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Jeeped suggested a UDF, so I figured I'd take a stab at it:

```
Function SUPERIF(LeftCondition, RightCondition, Optional Operator = "EQUALS", Optional Side = "LEFT")
Dim Result

If (Side = "LEFT") Then
    Result = LeftCondition
    ElseIf (Side = "RIGHT") Then
    Result = RightCondition
    Else
    SUPERIF = xlErrValue
End If

If (Operator = "EQUALS") Then
    If (LeftCondition = RightCondition) Then
    SUPERIF = Result
    Else
    SUPERIF = False
    End If
End If

If (Operator = "GREATER") Then
    If (LeftCondition > RightCondition) Then
    SUPERIF = Result
    Else
    SUPERIF = False
    End If
End If

If (Operator = "GRTEQL") Then
    If (LeftCondition >= RightCondition) Then
    SUPERIF = Result
    Else
    SUPERIF = False
    End If
End If

If (Operator = "LESS") Then
    If (LeftCondition < RightCondition) Then
    SUPERIF = Result
    Else
    SUPERIF = False
    End If
End If

If (Operator = "LESSEQL") Then
    If (LeftCondition <= RightCondition) Then
    SUPERIF = Result
    Else
    SUPERIF = False
    End If
End If

If (Operator = "NOT") Then
    If (LeftCondition <> RightCondition) Then
    SUPERIF = Result
    Else
    SUPERIF = False
    End If
End If

End Function
```

This would be entered as a formula like so: `=SUPERIF(A1, B1, "GREATER", "RIGHT")` Which would test to see if A1 is greater than B1, and if so it returns the value from B1.

I made the last two arguments optional, with default values of "EQUALS" and "LEFT", so you could just write `SUPERIF([some formula], [some other formula])` and as long as the results of both are the same then if will return the value on the left. For the sample you provided, it would be written as `=SUPERIF($B$4+13,7)`

Note, if you use UDFs then you'll need to save your workbook with macros enabled (*.xlsm).